# How to Access virtual box ‘Windows 11’ remotly

Tags: macos, ssh, virtualbox, remote-desktop, windows-11

I need help in accessing windows on virtual box from mac OS with Remote Desktop.

Host: mac os
Guest: windows 11

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting the VM in Bridged network mode in Virtualbox for easy access over LAN.

Do the following:

1. On the Windows 11 VM, Run CMD as administrator
2. Type in: `reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f` - This will  enable the RDP service.
3. Type in `ipconfig` to get the IPv4 address of that VM, you will need to remember this.
4. From your MacOS, have Microsoft Remote Desktop installed
5. Open it up and add the connection. Have the PC name set with the IPv4 address we gathered from the VM
6. Fill in the credentials. Try to connect

If it doesn't see the RDP open port from the VM, it may be that the Windows 11 Firewall is blocking this or the RDP service has not started.

You can check if RDP is enabled by doing the following from this link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-remote-desktop-5fe128d5-8fb1-7a23-3b8a-41e636865e8c

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work